# Show but disable a view in Eclipse-RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have two views in my RCP application, wherein I'm performing a task(background operation),the status of the operation is shown in view1. What I'm trying to achieve is that,during the task in progress, user shouldn't able to move/traverse to other views.They(other views) should be disabled.

As a workaround i tried using the showView method of IWorkbenchPage.

```
activePage.showView(view.ID,null,IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);
```

I've used the three constants VIEW_VISIBLE,VIEW_ACTIVATE,VIEW_CREATE. None worked in my case though.By the way in showView method signature, i could not figure out what is a secondary id.

Below is the simulated demo of my problem
[image]

here the user can traverse to view Demo,during the operation, which shouldn't be actually.
How can i resolve this, any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really disable a view (there is no notion of "disabled views"). The only thing you can do is hide it. Use the hideView() method to do that.

Comment: gratitude for valuable suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it would be to use the `ProgressService` to display a modal progress dialog while the operation is progressing. This way the user must wait until the operation is complete before they can interact with the UI.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService().run(true, false, runnable);
```

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_should_I_use_the_new_progress_service%3F

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a view like you disable any other SWT control: by setting `setEnabled(false)` on the top `Composite`. Often done by overriding `ViewPart.showBusy(...)`...